# Model's loss weights

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

I've model with two output layers, age and gender prediction layers. I want to assign different  weight values for each output layer's loss. I've the following line of code to do so.

```
model.compile(loss=[losses.mean_squared_error,losses.categorical_crossentropy], optimizer='sgd',loss_weights=[1,10])
```

My question is what is the effect of loss weights on performance of a model? How can I configure the loss weights so that the model can perform better on age prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will affect how the backpropagation for each of these outputs will cause the intermediate nodes within the network to be updated. If the output nodes' error were equal then the gradient descent process of the intermediate nodes will favor the resulting error of each of these outputs equally. By more heavily weighting an output node it means that the gradient descent will favor a set of parameters that perform better on that output node.